# Can not install "wfastcgi 2.1 gateway for iis and python 2.7.9" in IIS

Tags: django, iis, wfastcgi

I have a error installing "wfastcgi 2.1 gateway for iis and python 2.7.9" in IIS, to deploy an app django in windows 10. 
I can not download the installer (see the image).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI0Gs.png)

Please, have someone the installer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like Web Platform Installer. That feed is not maintained anymore, and it points to files on CodePlex which no longer exist now that CodePlex is closed/archived.

We recommend you install from https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/ instead, using pip.

Comment: Is there any other documentation on this? Is there any way to get the feed updated? Thanks though for the pointer, I'm going to see if I can get it to work and answer some of my own questions above!