# Web Platform Installer: Python Installer - Downloaded file failed signature verification and may have been tampered with

Tags: iis, web-platform-installer, iis-manager, wfastcgi

I'm trying to install WFastCGI 2.1 Gateway for IIS and Python 3.4 via the Web Platform Installer in Microsoft Server Manager's IIS Manager.

Python Installer fails with the error: "This product did not install successfully: Downloaded file failed signature verification and may have been tampered with". Python 3.4.2 (32-bit) and WFastCGI 2.1 Gateway for IIS and Python 3.4 subsequently fail with the error: "This product cannot be installed because a product that it depends on did not install successfully".

I noticed that the direct download link in the prerequisites tab launches [this URL](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=pytools), which explains that pytools has been migrated to PTVS. Maybe this is part of the problem?

I'm following [this tutorial](http://netdot.co/2015/03/09/flask-on-iis/) about deploying a Flask web app on IIS. Please help me find solutions to make this installation successful or provide alternatives that will allow me to deploy on IIS. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, ever have any luck? There's a similar question (for the 2.7 installer) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283691/can-not-install-wfastcgi-2-1-gateway-for-iis-and-python-2-7-9-in-iis that points to the wfastcgi Python project page: https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/ which supports Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue, and as [mgrollins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3911355/mgrollins) mentioned on his comment, using wfastcgi directly is the solution.

In my case I followed a very similar tutorial ([here](https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8)) up to where you finish installing IIS, then instead of installing the Web Platform Installer, I downloaded Python from python.org, installed it (for all users and adding to PATH), performed the "Downloading Package" and "Enabling wfastcgi" steps from the wfastcgi project page, https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/, meaning:

```
pip install wfastcgi 

wfastcgi-enable
```

After that you can continue following the tutorial from where it says "Setup your site - copy the wfastcgi.py " . (I found the wfastcgi.py file on the Scripts folder of the Python Install directory)

Another item worth mentioning, during “Add Module Mapping” there should be a | between the Python.exe and your site directory, if you miss it the side won't load, so for example it should look like:

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\wfastcgi.py
```